# Give dummy image natural width and height to act responsively

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, dimensions, aspect-ratio

I'm using [jQuery Lazyload Plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload). Before the images are loaded I use a dummy image as placeholder which is a 20x20 pixels blank PNG. Also I'm using [jQuery wookMark](https://github.com/GBKS/Wookmark-jQuery) which is a dynamic grid plugin. For this plugin to work I need the images to be in their correct aspect ratio so the plugin can calculate the suitable position of each grid element in the page.

I have `width` and `height` attributes on `img` tag set to the correct dimensions, but that doesn't have any effect on the dummy image and it will be shown as a square, no matter what.

I can use inline styles to set width and height for each image, but this approach will stop the image from being responsive in other dimensions.

Is there a way to give an image width and height in a way that it act like it is its real dimensions?

Here's the pen to look at:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iaIoJ

Comment: can you please show how does your dummy images look like ? and fiddle your code ?

Comment: only way that width and height attributes on img won't work is that you're overridding them with css.

Comment: @ProllyGeek I've added the pen to the question.
@Zentoaku Good point! You've answered half of my question. Now if I don't overwrite the width and height using css the image will not be responsive. To understand the problem change the `figure`'s width in the pen example above.

Comment: @NOjAN would you define responsive ? ofcourse you can make your image holder responsive but either width or height have to be auto , and your pen doesnt clarify the exact problem , via a simple script you can fetch the loaded image dimensions and set the holder to that dimension even before the image is loaded , but please give a live example.

Comment: @ProllyGeek Maybe I haven't explained it properly. Well, here it is: I need a random image (a 20x20 pixels PNG in this case) to keep it's 300x400 pixels aspect ratio no matter how wide it's parent is.

Comment: @NOjAN if you check the wookmark site itself : http://www.wookmark.com/ , you will find out that it is pretty easy to accomplish , you still dont give a live example so that i can help directly.

Comment: @ProllyGeek there's some nice imagery there for motivation if you keep scrolling :P

Comment: @ProllyGeek Forget wookMark and lazyload.. It's a pure HTML/CSS problem.

Comment: @NOjAN would you just give an example with some images and their placeholders ? is this hard to make ? just several images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good way for it.It's not going to be pure css, but that's fine by me :)

My solution is to set the image `height` to `0` and use `padding-bottom` to maintain the aspect ratio:

```
<img src="./blank.png" style="height:0;padding-bottom:133.333%">
```

And also having a `class` for the `img` tag when the actual image is loaded:

```
img.loaded {
    height:auto !important;
    padding-bottom:0 !important;
}
```

Here's the pen for this example: http://codepen.io/nOji/pen/yoshA

Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Seems very hackish, have you tested this in other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you're going to get what you want is by using some javascript. You're already using jQuery so that will make it a bit easier.

Use the following CSS to begin with (as an example):

```
.myImage {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

then when the images are loaded (in some sort of callback function I presume):

```
$('.myImage').css('width','100%');
$('.myImage').css('height','auto');
```

Alternatively, you can work with a `placeHolder` css class that has this height and widht, and then `$('myImage').removeClass('placeHolder');` to clear it from the images.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wish it was this easy, but this is not the answer I'm looking for. With your approach the placeholder image will not be responsive (100% width and keeping it's aspect ratio) when it's parent's width changes!